# How to access List elements with specific multiple index

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

I need to store every fifth element, with the result:

```
result=[5,10,15]
```

Comment: Use an extended slice, which allows you to specify a step value: `result = list[5::5]`

Comment: You can use `l[4::5]`

Answer (score 3):

```
    list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    results = list[4::5]
```

Here you go!